# Convert 2D Plotly Scattergeo to 3D Orthographic

Tags: plotly, orthographic

I'd like to convert this simple Plotly 2D map to a 3D orthographic projection but can't seem to find the right spot to place projection:"orthographic" in the data structure below. Thanks for the help!

```
from plotly.graph_objs import Scattergeo, Layout
from plotly import offline

data = [{
    'type': 'scattergeo',
    'lon': [85],
    'lat': [23],
    'marker':{
        'symbol':0,
        'size': 20,
        },
    }]

my_layout = Layout(title='Chart 1')

fig = {'data': data, 'layout': my_layout}
offline.plot(fig, filename='First_Chart_1.html')
```